# Why is a linear mapping $T: V\to W$ with dim($V$) = dim($W$) always an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

I thought I understood the idea of isomorphisms (because I understand surjectivity and injectivity) but then came across a theorem referenced in the title.

To be clear: $T: V \to W$ is an isomorphism iff $T$ is surjective and injective. But take the zero transformation, $T: V$ $\to$ $W$ where dim($V$) $=$ dim($W$) but $T$ is not surjective (Ker($T$) $= V$ $\to$ Im($T$) = 0) and hence cannot be isomorphic.

Can someone clear up this confusion, because either there's something wrong with my counterexample, or I don't understand the theorem.

Comment: The statement in the title is false, as you noted. What is true is that any onto map or any injective linear map between space of the same finite dimension is an isomorphism.

Comment: Yes of course. But I just reread the theorem in my book to make sure I'm not crazy and it makes no assumption of T being either injective or surjective. It just says "If $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces, then there is an isomorphism $T: V \to W$ iff dim($V$) = dim($W$)."

Comment: @PedroTamaroff The title is a question not a statement...? Vacuous truth? $1=2 \to 4=26$ right?

Comment: That is a very different statement than what's in your title

Comment: The statement in your book says that "there exists" an isomorphism if $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension. NOT that any linear map between them is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Nick OH I see.

Answer (score 0):

If dim(V)=dim(W) map vectors with the same coordinate representation in your favorite pair of bases B(V),B(W). This is obviously an isomorphism. if (WLOG) dim(V)

Comment: if you go into the edit menu you can view my solution in full without interference from the faschists.